# Using MutationObserver based on external condition ~ React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mutation-observers

I have a toggle button that automatically turns all the text in the HTML bold, and another one that changes the font of all the text. The only problem is that after the functions are called, they wont work on stuff that appeared after the button was pressed.

I'm pretty sure i need to use the MutationObserver so that it does something when the 'bold' toggle is active and something else when the 'font' toggle is active when it detects changes in the HTML. So far i've tried to use a UseState variable inside the MutationObserver Callback, but it wont work. it seems that the state of isBold and isFont flickers from 'true' to 'false' randomly inside this CallBack.

```
const [isBold, setIsBold] = useState(false)
const [isFont, setIsFont] = useState(false)

const handler = useCallback(mutationList => { 
        if(isBold){
                console.log("reapply boldness to HTML...");
        }
        if(isFont){
                console.log("reapply font to HTML...");
        }
}, [isBold, isFont]);

const observer = new MutationObserver(handler)

observer.observe(document.body, {
        subtree: true, 
        childList: true
})
```

Comment: It's unclear what the result should be. Should `setMoFlag(MoFlag+1)` trigger whenever the `isBold` or `isFont` state is changed? The Mutation Observer is not the way to go. React needs to act based on changed of state, not changes in HTML.

Comment: Sorry, deleted that part for confusing and irrelevant. My only question in that was why does ```setMoFlag(MoFlag+1)``` dosnt change its state inside the CallBack

Comment: At the moment there is no `setMoFlag(MoFlag+1)` in your `useCallback`. Are you sure this is the code related to your question?

Comment: common js-libs have an update function for those things, to update themselves about the state  of the current document or element